# Unable of passing data from UIPickerView to CustomTableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield

Im tryin something relative simple but I can't fin the way around this. I have a register view controller in which a UITableView is embedded. The TableView has CustomsCells has embedded three kinds of custom cells. The last one is customize with a UITextfield and when selected is suppose to trigger from the bottom the PickerView so the user can select form there the desire preference. Everything is working fine except one little thing; when any row is selected text should be the input of the textfield, but this is not happening.

I have tried several pieces of code on the internet, but most of them are about the textfield being in the same ViewController, as in this case the UITextFieldDelegate field is connected to de CustomTableViewCell class. I have tried creating an object of this CustomTableViewCell and then just tap on the textfield variable and tried to change the text property, but the outcome is just blank.

```
import UIKit

class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

    let registrationCell = RegisterViewCell()
    let personalCell = PersonalViewCell()
    var selectedRow : String = ""

    let registerArray = ["UserName"]
    let passwordArray = ["Password", "Confirm Password"]
    let personalArray = ["I am"] //Identity of the user, female or male
    let personalPickerArray = ["Famale", "Male"]
    @IBOutlet weak var registerTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var personalPickerView: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        personalPickerView.isHidden = true
        personalCell.personalTextField?.inputView = personalPickerView

    }
```

I have created extensions for the TableView and Picker View where I Think the problem is is here but I'm not sure:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let personalCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PersonalViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PersonalViewCell
            personalCell.personalLabel?.text = personalArray[0]
            personalCell.personalTextField.text = selectedRow
            personalCell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
            return personalCell
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row == 3 {
            personalPickerView.isHidden = false
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        let row = personalPickerArray[row]
        selectedRow = row
        personalPickerView.isHidden = true
        print(selectedRow)
    }
```

The Custom Cell Class file

```
import UIKit

class PersonalViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var personalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var personalTextField: UITextField!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

Right now when a row is selected im expecting to have an input in the UITextField embedded inside the Custom Cell "Personal View Cell" but when any row is selected the UITextField is just blank

Comment: Are you trying to get the picker value into the text field or the text field value into the picker?

Comment: Hello thank you for checking, I’m trying to get the picker value into the text field.

Comment: You can store the `indexPath` of the text field row, and when the picker `delegate` is called use the method `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)` to get the text field cell and then update the text field with your picker value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class RegisterViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedIndexPath:IndexPath?
    /* code for class  */


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var selectedIndexPath = indexPath //store index path
        if indexPath.row == 3 {
            personalPickerView.isHidden = false
        }
    }


 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        let row = personalPickerArray[row]
        selectedRow = row
        personalPickerView.isHidden = true

       /* check if we have an index path, and if the cell is correct type */
        if let indexPath = selectedIndexPath {
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? PersonalViewCell {
                   cell.textField.text = personalPickerArray[row]
             }
        }

        print(selectedRow)
    }

}
```